# Logstash: what will the KIBANA URL if there are 2 Elastic search instances on the same machine

Tags: logstash, kibana

What will be the URL if there are 2 elastic search instances on the same machine, say for example a Logstash config file is redirecting to embedded elastic search and the other pointing to the external ES instance both on the same machine.
How to differentiate the two?

By default we are accessing the KIBANA using URL: http://:9292

Answer (score 0):

So far, Kibana 3 do not support this, if this two elasticsearch instances are not at the same cluster. So, you have to setup two kibana for each elasticsearch instance.

You can follow this [discussion](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/214) about the feature you want.